# Sum of values in loop and keeping highest value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to calculate the shipping dimensions of multiple products. I want to return the largest value of `@tempLength` and `@tempWidth` and sum up all `@tempHeight`s in my loop:

```
@tempLength = 0
@tempWidth = 0
@tempHeight = 0

params[:rate][:items].each do |item|
  item = item[:product_id]
  puts "Item details"
  puts item
  @productDimensions = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
  @tempLength = @productDimensions.length
  @tempWidth = @productDimensions.width
  @tempHeight = @productDimensions.height
  # tempLength = maximum length value
  # tempWidth = maximum width value
  # tempHeight = sum of all heights
end
```

I know I have to use `sum(&:symbol)`, but I'm stuck. What's the best approach?

Comment: Stupid question: How about simply using '+' to get the sum and comparison operators to identify the max?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stephanie.  Still learning, and I was a bit reluctant to post the message in fear of it being a stupid question.

Comment: Just to prevent any misunderstanding: I was rather referring to my question being stupid not yours - what I was proposing is exactly what @widjajayd gave as an answer.

Comment: You should use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` for variable names. And try to find more expressive names, maybe `max_length` or `total_height` instead of `temp_...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here probably can help

```
@tempLength = 0
@tempWidth = 0
@tempHeight = 0
params[:rate][:items].each do |item|
  item = item[:product_id]
  puts "Item details"
  puts item
  @productDimensions = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
  @tempLength = @tempLength + @productDimensions.length
  @tempWidth  = @tempWidth  + @productDimensions.width
  if @productDimensions.height > @tempHeight
    @tempHeight = @productDimensions.height 
  end
end
# @tempLength = total of all tempLength values
# @tempWidth = total of all tempHeight values
# @tempHeight = keep highest value
```

Comment: It should be the other way round: determine maximum length / width and sum the heights.

Comment: there two things from the comments before source code he is asking about highest height but from the source code he wrote @tempheight as highest value, but I think he get my message

Comment: Oh, indeed, that is rather confusing :-)

Comment: thanks for working out my mess @widjajayd, what you assumed was correct.

Comment: @rlsaj as you probably know, there's an _edit_ button under your question, so you can still clarify / fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another suggestion that may result in better performance:

```
@tempLength = 0
@tempWidth = 0
@tempHeight = 0
product_ids = []
params[:rate][:items].each do |item|
  product_ids << item[:product_id]
end

# Filter products according to collected product_ids
@products = Product.where(:product_id => product_ids)

# Let ActiveRecord do the work
@tempLength = @products.sum('length')
@tempWidth  = @products.sum('width')
@tempHeight = @products.maximum('height')

# @tempLength = total of all tempLength values
# @tempWidth = total of all tempHeight values
# @tempHeight = keep highest value
```